# How do I access all the information for a Square transaction?

Tags: square, squarespace

I am a student (so I am pretty new to all of this stuff) trying to create a database for a coffee shop that uses Square for their register and website.  I want the database to update with all the information from a transaction every time one is completed.

I have a webhook that gets me the IDs every time a transaction completes, I can send the transaction ID to the Square API with an http request and get back information about the payment, but I still cannot figure out how to get the rest of the transaction information.  We want to query the database about what kinds of items are being sold when and with what modifiers, but so far the only way I can get that is through downloading a csv file with the item line information from the Square Dashboard.

If there is a way to get the line item information in some kind of way that can be automatically added to the database, I would really appreciate the help.  I have been looking for a solution and cannot find it on my own.

Answer (score 0):

For in-person payments the only way to see itemizations is to use V1 `ListPayments` (or `RetrievePayment`).

In order to see itemizations for online payments, you must utilize Square's `Orders API`. The workflow would be:

1. Create an order (`CreateOrder`) with `line_items` (can be ad-hoc, or use Catalog ids). Save the `order_id` for the next step.
2. When calling `Charge`, pass in the `order_id` from the previous step.

Once you are successfully attaching the `order_id`'s, when you retrieve a transaction you will be able to call the `BatchRetrieveOrders` endpoint with the `order_id` to see the itemizations.

References:
[V1 Payments](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1#navsection-payments)

[Orders Overview](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/products/orders/overview)

[Orders Reference](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#navsection-orders)